# How to simplify usage of nullable booleans in C#

Tags: c#, boolean, nullable, ternary-operator

Here is some example code to get started:

```
class Foo
{
   public bool? IsValid { get; set; }
}

// later in some other function...
void DoStuff( Foo myFoo )
{
   myControlState.Visible = myFoo.IsValid.HasValue ? myFoo.IsValid.Value : false;
}
```

I run into a lot of situations where I have to use a ternary operator like above to properly use a nullable bool. It would be nice if there was a slightly simpler way of getting the value of the bool without throwing exceptions. The code above seems straight-forward but there are much more complex situations where this ends up being a lot of code. I was hoping for something simple like:

```
myControlState.Visible = GetNullableValue<bool>( myFoo );
```

Does anyone have any cleaner alternatives to the ternary operator?

Comment: The real solution is to never use Nullable<bool>, but for some reason API's do. I never understood why I would want a bool with 3 options...

Comment: @monadic: My example is out of context, so naturally it doesn't make sense. In my real code, I am dealing with nullable bit fields in SQL server and mapping that to a property in a class, so of course it is important for me to have tri-valued booleans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) if that makes it more readable.

```
myControlState.Visible = myFoo.IsValid ?? false;
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. Just out of curiosity, how do you pronounce "coalescing"?

Comment: like "koa lessing"

Answer (score 1):

This is more elegant

```
 myControlState.Visible = myFoo.IsValid ?? false;
```

Comment: pretty sure @Bala just said this

Answer (score 1):

```
myControlState.Visible = myFoo.IsValid.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading bit values from the SQL server and want to check against null errors, Use the following Extension method against the data Row

```
public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this DataRow row, string key)
{
    return row.GetValueOrDefault(key, default(T));
}
```

and when you are reading data from the SQL server put in.

```
 Boolean IsVisible = GetValueOrDefault<string>("FieldName");
```